# Assigning value to the variable present in previous line using $ sign

Tags: assembly, dos, masm, x86-16

I'm trying to understand the MS-DOS v2.0 [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS), and in particular some of the code in [MSDATA.ASM](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/80ab2fddfdf30f09f0a0a637654cbb3cd5c7baa6/v2.0/source/MSDATA.ASM). This code was originally assembled with a 35+ year old MASM assembler (a version that wasn't commercially available). The code I'm interested in is near the beginning:

```
SUBTTL Initialized data and data used at DOS initialization
PAGE
; DATA AREA for MS-DOS

IFNDEF  KANJI
KANJI   EQU     0       ;FALSE
ENDIF

CONSTANTS       SEGMENT BYTE PUBLIC 'CONST'
        EXTRN   international_table:BYTE
        EXTRN   Current_Country:WORD


        ORG     0
CONSTRT EQU     $               ; Start of constants segment

        PUBLIC  DevStrLen
DEVSTRLEN DB    3              ; Size of below
        PUBLIC  DevString
DEVSTRING DB    "DEV"          ; Dummy device directory

;
; Table of routines for assignable devices
;
; MSDOS allows assignment if the following standard devices:
;   stdin  (usually CON input)
;   stdout (usually CON output)
;   auxin  (usually AUX input)
;   auxout (usually AUX output)
;   stdlpt (usually PRN output)
;
; SPECIAL NOTE:
;   Status of a file is a strange idea.  We choose to handle it in this manner:
;   If we're not at end-of-file, then we always say that we have a character.
;   Otherwise, we return ^Z as the character and set the ZERO flag.  In this
;   manner we can support program written under the old DOS (they use ^Z as EOF
;   on devices) and programs written under the new DOS (they use the ZERO flag
;   as EOF).

; Default FCBs for boot up

sftabl      LABEL   DWORD                     ; file table
            DW      -1
            DW      -1
            DW      sf_default_number  ; Number of entries in table
            DB      sf_default_number DUP ( (SIZE sf_entry) DUP (0))

        I_AM    NoSetDir,BYTE           ; true -> do not set directory
        I_am    DidCTRLC,BYTE           ; true -> we did a ^C exit
        I_am    SpaceFlag,BYTE          ; true -> embedded spaces are allowed
                                        ; in FCB
; the next two variables relate to the position of the logical stdout/stdin
; cursor.  They are only meaningful when stdin/stdout are assigned to the
; console.

        i_am    CARPOS,BYTE             ; cursor position in stdin
        i_am    STARTPOS,BYTE           ; position of cursor at beginning
                                        ; of buffered input call
        I_AM    PFLAG,BYTE
        I_AM    VERFLG,BYTE             ; Initialize with verify off
        I_AM    CONTPOS,WORD
        PUBLIC  CHARCO
CHARCO      DB      00000011B           ; Allows statchks every 4 chars...

        I_AM    DMAADD,DWORD            ; User's disk transfer address
                                        ; (disp/seg)
            ORG     $-CONSTRT-4
            DW      80H
            DW      ?

ENDMEM      DW      ?
```

I'm trying to understand this code in particular:

```
        I_AM    DMAADD,DWORD            ; User's disk transfer address
                                        ; (disp/seg)
            ORG     $-CONSTRT-4
            DW      80H
            DW      ?

ENDMEM      DW      ?
```

It appears to define a DWORD public variable `DMAADD` then it assigns the variable `DMAADD` the values `80H` to the first word and then `?` to the second word. I have some doubt in my mind and perhaps the most important question is - why is it doing it this way, instead of just assigning value of `80H` to the variable `DMAADD` to the next line. Why is this strategy being applied here, and what is its purpose? WHy the `ORG     $-CONSTRT-4`?

---

The `I_AM` macro is defined and described this way:

```
;
; define a data item to be public and of an appropriate size/type
;
I_AM    MACRO   name,size
    PUBLIC  name

    IFIDN <size>,<WORD>
        name    DW  ?
    ELSE
        IFIDN <size>,<DWORD>
            name    DD  ?
        ELSE
            IFIDN <size>,<BYTE>
                name    DB  ?
            ELSE
                name    DB  size DUP (?)
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
ENDM
```

Comment: I mentioned this question as a separate one because my previous questions still got importance, so I didn't delete them.

Comment: Does [Meaning of “?” (Question Mark) in assembly](https://superuser.com/questions/939338/meaning-of-question-mark-in-assembly) or [What does dw, db and ? (question mark) mean in TASM struc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934080/what-does-dw-db-and-question-mark-mean-in-tasm-struc) not answer your question? `80h` is the x86 kernel interrupt for executing the command currently in the register(s). There is an entire domain name [int80h.org - What is int 80h?](http://int80h.org/)

Comment: Given your multiple questions on Assembly, I would recommend looking at [**The Art of Assembly Language Programming (all books)**](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/). The [DOS 16-Bit Edition](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/DOS/index.html) contains the most concise presetnation of material.

Comment: I added some comments in line number "1042". This code written is of msdos, not Unix which supports interrupt 80h. So I might guess that here "80H" is the boot drive code which requires "80H" in the beginning. "80H" decides from which drive will the system be booted.

Comment: It would appear you are trying to figure out [MS-DOS v2.0 MSDATA.ASM file](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/master/v2.0/source/MSDATA.ASM). If it isn't that then just post a link where we can find the code.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/80ab2fddfdf30f09f0a0a637654cbb3cd5c7baa6/v2.0/source/MSDATA.ASM                In line numbers 15 and 67.

Comment: Excellent Michael you got the right point. It is really that  file please explain me that code. How the function will work.

Comment: I think your previous series of questions are all duplicates of this.  The key thing is how `ORG  $-CONSTRT-4` works, where `CONSTRT` was defined earlier.  And that's what's going on in your previous questions, too.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the developers were intent on using the `I_AM` macro to make symbols (that point at BYTEs, WORDs, and DWORDs) publicly accessible by other modules. The problem is that the `I_AM` macro doesn't allow you to specify the data, it leaves it uninitialised as `?`. To get around that the developers decided to back the program counter up to overwrite the uninitialised data so they could fill it in with a WORD value of 80h and a second WORD that is uninitialised (`?`).

You aren't allowed to use an expressions with an `org` that is negative. You couldn't back the program counter up with:

```
org -4
```

You need an absolute value. You need to know how far the program counter is from the beginning of the segment. They chose to do that by setting up `CONSTRT` at the top with:

```
CONSTANTS       SEGMENT BYTE PUBLIC 'CONST'
        EXTRN   international_table:BYTE
        EXTRN   Current_Country:WORD


        ORG     0
CONSTRT EQU     $               ; Start of constants segment
```

In this case `CONSTRT` is given the value 0 (the start of the segment). `$` is the current program counter relative to the beginning of the segment.

To determine the absolute value of the current program counter 4 bytes earlier you can take the current program counter `$` and subtract it from the program counter at the beginning of the segment (which `CONSTRT` is set to). Once you know how far you are from the beginning of the segment you subtract 4.

What we have then is:

```
    I_AM    DMAADD,DWORD            ; User's disk transfer address
                                    ; (disp/seg)
```

That defines a publicly accessible label that is defined as pointing at an uninitialised DWORD value. This backs up the program counter by 4 to replace the uninitialised DWORD:

```
        ORG     $-CONSTRT-4
```

This then emits the WORD value 80h followed by an uninitialised WORD value:

```
        DW      80H
        DW      ?
```

You could have replaced the `I_AM` macro, the backing up of the pointer and replacing of the data with:

```
        public DMAADD
        DMAADD dd 80h
```

It may be that the DOS developers always exported labels that point at BYTE, WORD, DWORD data via the `I_AM` macro as a coding requirement at Microsoft. This is entirely speculative. They may have felt that a common macro would allow them to change the method of exporting such data without changing code in countless places.

Comment: So `CONSTRT` is just a constant that needs to be defined as `0` to make `org $ - CONSTRT - 4` = `org $ - 4`?  I would have expected `org $ - 4` to work on its own.  (Of course `org -4` won't work; it takes an absolute not relative position.  But I don't see the need for `$ - symbol - 4`, unless that works around some assembler limitation.)

Comment: @PeterCordes : I should probably amend my answer to explain why `$-4`  probbly didn't work. MASM probably didn't see `$-4` as an absolute value so it isn't allowed in the expression. The old assemblers were finicky in this regard. It was why when I modified the question I put the note about the MASM being used being 35 years old and wasn't an officially version of a release product. The develoeprs were likely dealing with limitations of the assembler.

Comment: @Petercordes : I went back to MASM 1.0 (and 1.10) and both support `$-4` inside a segment. Hard to say.

Comment: I'd hate to think they didn't know you could use `$` that way in an expression. It is documented in the 1.00 manual or they started with even an earlier version of MASM that didn't support it. I don't know at this point.

Comment: Was DOS development started with an even earlier assembler?  This could be left over from even older code?

Comment: @PeterCordes It is possible that internally they started with some version that existed in an earlier state. Its the only thing that would make sense besides the developers now knowing of this feature.

Comment: @PeterCordes Unless they started with Macro-86. I'd have to see about the docs for that.

Comment: The Macro-86 manual says it is supported. So it could have been earlier than that lol

Comment: Or maybe someone just had a brain-fart and made it more complicated than necessary, perhaps because their original idea was more complicated.  I know I've written things that were (in hindsight) overcomplicated because I didn't see the problem from the perspective that made it simple.  A little weird here because the whole thing only makes sense if `CONSTRT = 0`, but IDK.

Comment: It's possible they were working around a bug in an assembler they were using, or they were using some crazy like the MACRO-10 assembler they used for their BASIC implementations. But it was probably just a mistake and they didn't understand how `$` or ORG worked. Back in the early 80's when the first versions of 86-DOS/MS-DOS were being written there wouldn't have been much opportunity for the developer(s) to play around with the assembler.